# limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1-\frac14)(1-\frac1{4^2})(1-\frac1{4^3})\cdots(1-\frac1{4^n})$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Can this limit be evaluated:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\frac14\right)\left(1-\frac1{4^2}\right)\left(1-\frac1{4^3}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac1{4^n}\right)$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is [Euler function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) and unfortunately it has no closed from.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $$A=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\Big(1-\frac{1}{a^k}\Big)$$ Take the logarithms; so $$\log(A)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\log\Big(1-\frac{1}{a^k}\Big)$$  Now, consider the Tylor expansion $$\log(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^5}{5}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ and set $x=\frac{1}{a^k}$; so the summation adds a series of geometric progressions.

Limiting to the given terms, you should arrive (for $a=4$) to $$\log(A)=-\frac{8176349}{21912660}$$ then $A \approx 0.688573$ while the result should be $A\approx 0.688538$; I hope this is not too bad for an approximation.